# Can I make a promise return a populated object in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to the whole set of Deferred/Promise principles, but after reading about it all I can find is about how to use them to return ajax data, not a javascript object. Is that possible? The goal is to make the following code work:

```
var Binary = function(data){
   this.data = data;
}

var File = function(url){
   this.data = null;
   this.url = url;
   this.getData = function(){ 
      // return either cached version at this.data or fetch it
   }
}

// the  goal is to make the following possible:
var url = "http://www.google.com/humans.txt";
var file = new File(url);
file.getData().done(function(binary){ //binary should be equals to `new Binary(data)`
    alert("we got binary data object with the data being: " + binary.data);
});
```

Comment: If your operation is sometimes async and sometimes synchronous, then you can return an already resolved promise for the synchronous path and then the caller can just treat the result as if it was async whether it was or wasn't.  If the result is always produced synchronously, then there's no reason to use promises.

Comment: Which Promise flavor would you like the answer in? [`jQuery.deferred`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/)? [ES6 Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)? Promises/A+?

Comment: @FabrícioMatté jQuery.deferred

Comment: @jfriend00 yes, i mean it to be sometimes synchronous sometimes asynchronous depending on if the result has been cached. I just dont know all the mechanics in doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this should work:

```
this.getData = function(){ 
   var deferred = $.Deferred();
   deferred.resolve(new Binary(this.data));
   return deferred.promise();
};
```

Instead of returning the data itself, you return a `promise`, which in this case has already been resolved, so the `done` callback can get called immediately with the data you resolve it with.

Answer (score 1):

The jquery ajax call returns a promise.
If you want to cache it, just 'pipe' your file instance into the return

```
this.getData = function(){ 
  if (!this.dataPromise){
      this.dataPromise = $.ajax(url).then(function(data){
          return new File(data);
      });
  } 
  return this.dataPromise;
};
```